# Lattice Points on Line Segments

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

> Let there be given nine lattice points (points with integral coordinates) in the three dimensional Euclidean space. Show that there is a lattice point on the interior of one of the line segments joining two of these points.
>
> *[PUTNAM, Problem 4](https://www.geneseo.edu/%7Etowsleyg/PUTNAM%20PROBLEM%20ARCHIVE.htm)*

I think this can be solved by forming 8 boxes then there are nine points so two must be of same category and so on. But I am unable to find the boxes.

Comment: Which contest is it from?

Comment: Hint: consider the coordinates of each lattice point $\mathrm{mod}\,2$

Comment: https://www.geneseo.edu/~towsleyg/PUTNAM%20PROBLEM%20ARCHIVE.htm  Problem 4

Comment: It is from PUTNAM

Comment: @Zac thanks I solved it.